# Selection of sites for wind power generation using time series from 600 candidate sites

Tags: time-series, correlation, optimization, decision-theory

I have 3 hourly power generation data for around 600 locations for a year. (i.e. 8 data per day for 365 days for each location.)

I want to find out a way where out of this 600 locations, I can say suppose choose suppose 10 locations which are producing power at different time periods.

suppose:

```
Location:   Hour 0, Hour 3, Hour 6, Hour 9, Hour 12,  Hour 15

   A          30       00      50      70       00      20    
   B          50       20      70     100       00      40
   C          00      100      20      00       40      30
   D          20       15      10      00       40      30
```

Here, A and B are highly correlated where A and C are inversely correlated. So, is there a way where I can distinguish the locations which are producing powers at different time periods so that, by accommodating these few location, the overall power generation can be sort of stable?

By sort of stable, I mean something like this which I mentioned in the comment later on to clarify my question.

Since A and C are inversely co-related, so if I choose power from A and C out of four locations, I would get some power all the time (always above 30 in this scenario). But if I take A and B, I would get very high amount of power when I have power (like 70+100=170 in hour 9), and I wont get any power at Hour 12 (since A and B produces 00 power in Hour 12).  I want to avoid choosing A and B, and I want to choose A and C.  My objective is to choose 10 locations out of 600 where by adding powers of each hour of 10 locations, total power for each hour should be above a certain threshold, like 30.

Comment: So, you want to choose 10 out of 600 locations and get a total that is "sort of stable". But what do you mean by "sort of stable"? If this is power generation, perhaps you want to have no hour when total power is below some number? Except, if this is power for human cities, the need will vary over the course of a day and a week (and, if it supplies heat and cooling, a year, depending on location). Also, do you want the *best* set of 10 (per some criterion) or simply a set that is *good enough*?

Comment: Since A and C are inversely co-related, so if i choose power from A and C out of four locations, I would get some power all the time (always above 30 in this scenario). 
But if i take A and B, I would get very high amount of power when I have power (like 70+100=170 in hour 9), and I wont get any power at Hour 12 (since A and B produces 00 power in Hour 12).
I want to avoid choosing A and B, and I want to choose A and C. 

my objective is to choose 10 locations out of 600 where by adding powers of each hour of 10 locations, total power for each hour should be above a certain threshold, like 40.

Comment: * threshold could be like 30* for this instance

Answer (score 0):

While correlation gives some useful information, it would be better to use a criterion specialized for purpose. What you need is stable supply of energy, supposedly you know what you need, and that may well be varying with time of year and time of day. Also, probably you have some cost of construction (and of operation) which may be varying with site.

This indicates to formulate the problem as an optimization problem, maybe using a mixed integer formulation (there are fast solvers today).  You would then minimize cost under restrictions that demand is satisfied.

Maybe even some form of *stochastic programming* may be of use.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stochastic+programming+answers%3A1